# Add user's mail to BCC with MFMailComposeViewController iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, sdk

Is it possible to add user's mail (mail used in "from" field) to bcc field automatically in code with MFMailComposeViewController component.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason why `setBccRecipients:` won't work for you? Did you bother to read the documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: setBccRecipients: work perfectly but I need to fill it with user's email automatically. This information is not accessible but is it possible to automatically add the "from" email to bcc?

Answer (score 1):

You cann't do it since there is no public API in iOS SDK to retrieve user's email.

You can try to use this https://github.com/0xced/ABGetMe project, but author noted:

> ABGetMe is not legally App Store compliant because it uses
>   undocumented APIs which is proscribed by clause 3.3.1 of the iPhone
>   Developer Program License Agreement. It is technically App Store
>   compliant though as it will pass the App Store validation. Moreover,
>   it should not crash even if the undocumented APIs change in the
>   future.